Different coloured text in hintText of TextField

I want to change the color of only "name" in "Search by name" to Colors.red.shade900. But the hintText field takes String as input. I know I can use hintStyle but it changes color all the hintText. Here is the code for this field:
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Search by name',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16,
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    ),
    prefixIcon: const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.search,
        size: 28,
      ),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
        width: 3,
      ),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
        width: 3,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
  ),
),

I have achieved this in regular text:

Using this code:
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      const TextSpan(
        text: 'Car ',
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: carId,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red.shade900,
        ),
      ),
    ],
    style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 28,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
)


Another alternative would be to create a custom icon showing the magnifying glass and the words "Search by". Franky, I would recommend removing the words "Search by" since the magnifying glass already implies a search of some kind.

If you take a look at the source code, the hint text rendering is hardcoded in the _InputDecoratorState class.
Specifically, in the build method of this class, the hint is created in line 2166:
final Widget? hint = hintText == null ? null : AnimatedOpacity(
  opacity: (isEmpty && !_hasInlineLabel) ? 1.0 : 0.0,
  duration: decoration.hintFadeDuration ?? _kHintFadeTransitionDuration,
  curve: _kTransitionCurve,
  child: Text(
    hintText!,
    style: hintStyle,
    textDirection: decoration.hintTextDirection,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    textAlign: textAlign,
    maxLines: decoration.hintMaxLines,
  ),
);

As you can see, the hint text is created as a single Text widget. There's no built-in way to apply different styles to different parts of the hint text.
You would need to modify the Flutter framework source code, specifically the InputDecorator class to achieve what you're asking for.
You'd basically  need to replace the Text widget with a RichText widget
(like in your example) that allows for different text spans with different styles.

So, either you copy over the InputDecorator file from Flutter and modify it (and probably rename the class to CustomInputDecorator) -- but that'll cause another issue, since a TextField's decoration property:
  const TextField({
    super.key,
    this.controller,
    this.focusNode,
    this.undoController,
    this.decoration = const InputDecoration(), // --> HERE

requires an InputDecoration. So you'ld also need to modify that.
Otherwise,  you'd probably want to create a Custom widget.
